# expanding regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

My program takes in a regex for describing a set of devices. For example,

```
--device=dev{01,02}{nyc}.hukka.com
```

should expand to dev01nyc.hukka.com and dev02nyc.hukka.com

How can I use the `re` module in Python to expand the user provided regex to complete strings that I can use? I am using Python 2.4.

Comment: This probably isn't possible. Regular expressions in general can accept languages that have an infinite amount of words, so RE libraries don't usually support trying to enumerate them.

Comment: What you've posted is not a regular expression.

Comment: You are essentially creating a new templating language. Be sure you really want that. unutbu does have the appropriate approach.

Answer (score 6):

If we [re.split](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.split) on the braces, we get:

```
In [7]: re.split(r'\{(.*?)\}',userstring)
Out[7]: ['--device=dev', '01,02', '', 'nyc', '.hukka.com']
```

Every other item in the list came from inside braces, which we next need to split on commas:

```
In [8]: [ part.split(',') if i%2 else [part]  for i,part in enumerate(re.split(r'\{(.*?)\}',userstring)) ]
Out[8]: [['--device=dev'], ['01', '02'], [''], ['nyc'], ['.hukka.com']]
```

Now we can use [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to enumerate the possibilities:

```
import re
import itertools

userstring = '--device=dev{01,02}{nyc}.hukka.com'

for x in itertools.product(*[ part.split(',') if i%2 else [part]  for i,part in
                              enumerate(re.split(r'\{(.*?)\}',userstring)) ]):
    print(''.join(x))
```

yields

```
--device=dev01nyc.hukka.com
--device=dev02nyc.hukka.com
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply by extract the first braces to a group and iterate over this group :

```
import re

user_arg = "dev{01,02}{nyc}.hukka.com"

regex = re.compile('dev{(?P<dev_id>[^}]*)}{(nyc)}.hukka.com')
result = regex.search(user_arg)

devices = []
for dev_id in result.group(1).split(',') :
    devices.append("dev%s%s.hukka.com" % (dev_id, result.group(2)))

print devices
```

That returns :

```
$ ['dev01nyc.hukka.com', 'dev02nyc.hukka.com']
```