# expand [x-y] and {a,b,c} in strings -- like glob(3) but without filename matching

Tags: c

I'm looking for a canned C routine that does what [`glob(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/glob) does, except *without* matching the results against filenames, e.g.

```
input: "x[1-4]y"
output: "x1y", "x2y", "x3y", "x4y"
```

regardless of whether any files with those names happen to exist.  **EDIT**: This doesn't need to produce the list all at once; in fact it would be better if it had an iterator-style "give me the next name now" API, as the list could be enormous.

Obviously this cannot support `*` and `?`, but that's fine; I only *need* the `[a-z]` notation.  Support for the `{foo,bar,baz}` notation would be nice too.

Best option is telling me the name of a routine that is already in everybody's C library that does this.  Second best would be a pointer to a chunk of BSD-licensed (or more permissively) code.  GPL code would be awkward, but I could live with it.

Comment: very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826499/expanding-regex-in-python

Comment: What about [`wordexp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/wordexp)?

Comment: @sleeplessnerd I need C.

Comment: @asaelr `wordexp`, like `glob`, will only produce a list of *filenames* that match a wildcard string.  In fact, it is my understanding that it uses `glob` internally.

Comment: Google helped me out: http://joseph.rezeau.pagesperso-orange.fr/eao/developpement/expandRegexpToString.htm

Comment: That's nice as a demo, but I need *code* that I can put into my *program*. A web service ain't gonna work.

Comment: I know :D but it proves that this stuff exists...

Comment: ... Oh, now I see it's JavaScript embedded in the page, not a web service.  Unfortunately, it would take me longer to translate that to C than it would to write what I need from scratch, and if I weren't under desperate time pressure right now I *would* just write it from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) (the command line tool, not the library) contains code that does this job, which is relatively easy to extract:

> https://github.com/bagder/curl/blob/master/src/tool_urlglob.c
>   https://github.com/bagder/curl/blob/master/src/tool_urlglob.h

They'll have to be edited to remove some dependencies on the guts of cURL that are not part of the public library interface.  The API is a little confusing, so here's some wrapper code I wrote:

```
#include "tool_urlglob.h"

struct url_iter
{
  char **upats;
  URLGlob *uglob;
  int nglob;
};

static inline struct url_iter
url_prep(char **upats)
{
  struct url_iter it;
  it.upats = upats;
  it.uglob = NULL;
  it.nglob = -1;
  return it;
}

static char *
url_next(struct url_iter *it)
{
  char *url;

  if (!it->uglob) {
    for (;;) {
      if (!*it->upats)
        return 0;
      if (!glob_url(&it->uglob, *it->upats, &it->nglob, stderr))
        break;
      it->upats++;
    }
  }

  if (glob_next_url(&url, it->uglob))
    abort();
  if (--it->nglob == 0) {
    glob_cleanup(it->uglob);
    it->uglob = 0;
    it->upats++;
  }
  return url;
}
```

Pass an array of strings to `url_prep`, call `url_next` on the result until it returns `NULL`.  Strings returned from `url_next` must be deallocated with `free` when you're done with them.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a sketch of how I'd write the iterator:

1. Count the instances of `[` in the string. This will be the number of "dimensions" you iterate over.
2. For each dimension, establish a range of values based on the number of characters in the bracket expression.
3. Simply iterate an n-tuple of integers over these ranges, and use the resulting values as indices into the bracket expressions to expand the string based on the values.

Comment: What part of "I'm looking for a _canned routine_" didn't you understand?  I know how to write the damn thing myself, if I only had the time!

Comment: I think you could have written it in less time than it took to write the question and downvote my answer.

Comment: You know what, I would take it as a personal favor if you refrained from answering or commenting on my questions at all in the future.